Change styling navbar from PrimeReact
I want to change the background color of the navbar that was created using PrimeReact. But I do not know where do I put the CSS styling. I try many time but none of them work. I only want to change the background color the rest of the default styling from PrimeReact I want to keep it.
import React from 'react';
import { Menubar } from 'primereact/menubar';
import { MenuItem } from 'primereact/menuitem';
import { Badge } from 'primereact/badge';

import 'primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css'; // Theme
import 'primereact/resources/primereact.min.css'; // Core
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css'; // Icons

import logo from './assets/logo.png';

export default function Testpages() {
    const itemRenderer = (item) => (
        <a>
            <span className={item.icon} />
            <span className="mx-2">{item.label}</span>
            {item.badge && <Badge className="ml-auto" value={item.badge} />}
            {item.shortcut && <span className="ml-auto border-1 surface-border border-round surface-100 text-xs p-1">{item.shortcut}</span>}
        </a>
    );
    const items: MenuItem[] = [
        {
            label: 'Home',
            icon: 'pi pi-home'
        },
        {
            label: 'Features',
            icon: 'pi pi-star'
        },
        {
            label: 'Projects',
            icon: 'pi pi-search',
        },
        {
            label: 'Contact',
            icon: 'pi pi-envelope',
        }
    ];

    return (
        <div className="w-full ">
            <div className="container mx-auto">
                <div className="logo-container flex justify-center py-4">
                    <img src={logo} alt="Logo" className="logo-image" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            <Menubar model={items} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}



You can add bg-primary and you can do the following to change the styling of the navigation bar:
 <Menubar className="bg-primary" model={items} />


You can create a css file e.g.: Testpages.css and you can do the following:
.p-menubar {
    background: red;
}

Your css file then should be imported in your jsx/tsx file after the imports of PrimeReact styles.
Another approach is to change the background inline like:
<Menubar style={{ background: "red" }} model={items} />

